# List<String> as command line argument in java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I want to give 3 inputs as command line arguments in Java:

1. `inputFileLocation`
2. `configFileList`
3. `outputFileLocation`

But I am not able to understand how to give list as command line arguement. I tried something like this:

```
public class BatchLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int argc = 0;
        String inputFileLocation = argc < args.length ? args[argc++] : null;
        String configFileList = argc < args.length ? args[argc++] : null;
        String outputFileLocation = argc < args.length ? args[argc++] : null;
        CaptureBatch captureBatch = new CaptureBatch();
        captureBatch.setInputFileLocation(inputFileLocation);
        captureBatch.setConfigFileList(configFileList);
        captureBatch.setOutputFileLocation(outputFileLocation);
    }
}
```

I am getting a compile-time error at `captureBatch.setConfigFileList(configFileList);`.

The input will be given like this :

```
D:/input a.conf,b.conf,c.conf D:/output
```

where `D:/input` is the `inputFileLocation`,
`a.conf,b.conf,c.conf` is the `configFileList` with `,` separators, and
`D:/output` is the `outputFileLocation`.

Comment: Arrays.asList(configFileList.split(",")) will give you the list.

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments are aggregated into an `String[]` in Java and passed into your `main` un-processed.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) { // code }
```

With your example input of `D:/input a.conf,b.conf,c.conf D:/output` the value of `args` becomes `["D:/input", "a.conf,b.conf,c.conf", "D:/output"]` where the `[]` delimit an array of `String`.

You have two options:

1. manually parse this `args` array and pull it apart manually and process each element yourself. In this case you need to `Arrays.asList(args[2].split(","));` the second argument to get it into a `List<String>` as you desire.
2. Use something like [JSAP ( Java Simple Argument Parser )](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/) and let a well tested and mature library parse, validate and format the input for you. [Specifically it can parse the second argument you are passing in for you.](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/doc/ch10.html)

Needless to say, I prefer the second option because the first is just brittle busy work.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int argc = 0;
    if(args.length>2){
    String inputFileLocation = args[0];
    String configFileList = args[1];
    String outputFileLocation = args[2];

    List<String> lList=Arrays.asList(configFileList.split(","));
    System.out.println(inputFileLocation);
    System.out.println(lList);
    System.out.println(outputFileLocation);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

D:/input

[a.conf, b.conf, c.conf]

D:/output